# SQLAlchemy group_concat and duplicates

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

When I try to join a *many-to-many* table and group it by  the *main-id* I am getting **duplicates** when I add the second *many-to-many* table.

Here is how my models look like:

### Models

**user**

```
class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_fistName = db.Column(db.String(64))
    ...
```

**student_identifier**

```
student_identifier = db.Table('student_identifier',
    db.Column('class_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('class.class_id')),
    db.Column('id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
)
```

**class**

```
class Class(db.Model):
    sqlite_autoincrement=True
    class_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    class_name = db.Column(db.String(128), unique=True)
    mm_children = db.relationship('User', secondary=student_identifier, backref=db.backref('classes'))
```

**class_course_identifier**

```
class_course_identifier = db.Table('class_course_identifier',
    db.Column('course_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('course.course_id')),
    db.Column('class_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('class.class_id'))
)
```

**database structure**

[image: mydatabase - er diagram]

Well I am using SQLAlchemy to select the desired tables with the data I want. with this session.query

```
db.session.query(
   Class.class_id,
   Class.class_name,
   func.group_concat(User.user_fistName),
   func.group_concat(Course.course_name)
   ).filter(Class.courses, User.classes).group_by(Class.class_id)
```

the problem is that I am getting duplicates of both the courses AND names, so if the course has two users it will print the students and the course two times.
Here is how it is looking:

**wrong view**
[image: how it is looking right now]

And here is how it should look:

**correct view**
[image: the right way to look]

## the problem

the problem is coming when I am adding the second *many-to-many* table, for example users/student-identifier. If I remove the line where I "join" it, I am getting the duplicates. Is there anyway to correct this? Or should I use RAW-SQL instead(and if yes, how?)

Comment: Sidenote. I believe it's firstname instead of fistname

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Found out the solution, and it is quite simple.

**RAW SQL**

```
SELECT
  class.class_id,
  class.class_name,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT course.course_name),
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT user.user_fistName)  
FROM
  class
JOIN class_course_identifier ON class.class_id = class_course_identifier.class_id
JOIN course ON class_course_identifier.course_id = course.course_id
JOIN student_identifier ON class.class_id = student_identifier.class_id
JOIN user ON student_identifier.id = user.id
GROUP BY class.class_id
```

**SQLAlchemy**

```
db.session.query(
   Class.class_id,
   Class.class_name,
   func.group_concat(User.user_fistName.distinct()),
   func.group_concat(Course.course_name.distinct())
   ).filter(Class.courses, User.classes).group_by(Class.class_id)
```

Simply add the `distinct()` to the desired column you want to be unique

Comment: How did you access those grouped fields in your template, simply .user_firstName and .course_name?

Comment: Never mind, I added a .label() in lieu of the original field name which didn't allow me to access the grouped field.