# Is there a LISTAGG WITHIN GROUP equivalent in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy, oracle12c, listagg

Here is a simple Oracle table:

```
+-----------+---------+
|   food    | person  |
+-----------+---------+
| pizza     | Adam    |
| pizza     | Bob     |
| pizza     | Charles |
| ice cream | Donald  |
| hamburger | Emma    |
| hamburger | Frank   |
+-----------+---------+
```

And here are the results of an aggregated SELECT I'd like to do:

```
+-----------+------------------+
|   food    |      people      |
+-----------+------------------+
| hamburger | Emma,Frank       |
| ice cream | Donald           |
| pizza     | Adam,Bob,Charles |
+-----------+------------------+
```

With Oracle 11g+ this is easy enough with a LISTAGG:

```
SELECT food, LISTAGG (person, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY person) AS people
FROM mytable
GROUP BY food;
```

But I haven't been able to find a way to do this within SQLAlchemy.  An [old question from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28056121/list-agg-function-implemented-in-sqlalchemy-0-7) shows where someone was trying to implement a custom class to do the job, but is that really the best option there is?

MySQL has a `group_concat` feature, and thus [this questioner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583832/sqlalchemy-group-concat-and-duplicates) solved his problem with `func.group_concat(...)`.  Sadly that function is not available within Oracle.

Comment: No, `group_concat` (and therefore SQLAlchemy's `func.group_concat()` is only available in MySQL, not Oracle.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: I actually have to work on a number of Oracle installations, ranging from 11g (rel 2) to 12c.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQLAlchemy group\_concat and duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26583832/sqlalchemy-group-concat-and-duplicates)

Comment: @xfix I do have to question that as a dupe target. Though OP references it in their post, it does not solve their problem. There is no GROUP_CONCAT in Oracle according to OP.

Comment: @IljaEverilä Fair enough, retracting my close vote, should have checked this more carefully, but it seemed like the same thing reading only the title and Oracle in post content.

Comment: Yep, definitely not a duplicate since the "possible duplicate" solution only works for MySQL, not Oracle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beginning from [version 1.1](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/changelog/changelog_11.html#change-f1a5b143ac2614a44c4d4be425086e5e) you can use [`FunctionElement.within_group(*order_by)`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.FunctionElement.within_group):

```
In [7]: func.listagg(column('person'), ',').within_group(column('person'))
Out[7]: <sqlalchemy.sql.elements.WithinGroup object at 0x7f2870c83080>

In [8]: print(_.compile(dialect=oracle.dialect()))
listagg(person, :listagg_1) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY person)
```

Comment: Great - this is perfect!  There's still a remaining question about weird null characters in the separator string (see my own posted "answer"), but nevertheless this gets me 95% there.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Ilja's answer did the trick for me.  Here it is fully fleshed out, using SQLAlchemy 1.2.2 (I couldn't get it to work in 1.1.10, but upgrading took care of that)

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from lib import project_config
from sqlalchemy import func

db_url = 'oracle://someuser:somepassword@some_connect_string'    

Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine(db_url, echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    food   = Column(String(30), primary_key=True)
    person = Column(String(30), primary_key=True)

Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

session.add(MyTable(food='pizza', person='Adam'))
session.add(MyTable(food='pizza', person='Bob')) 
session.add(MyTable(food='pizza', person='Charles'))
session.add(MyTable(food='ice cream', person='Donald'))
session.add(MyTable(food='hamburger', person='Emma'))  
session.add(MyTable(food='hamburger', person='Frank'))
session.commit()

entries = session.query(
      MyTable.food,
      func.listagg(MyTable.person, ',').within_group(MyTable.person).label('people')
    ).group_by(MyTable.food).all()

[print('{}: {}'.format(entry.food, entry.people)) for entry in entries]
```

which prints out:

```
hamburger: Emma,Frank
ice cream: Donald
pizza: Adam,Bob,Charles
```

which is great!  The only remaining mystery is why the separator character (,) is preceded by a NULL:

```
>>> print(entries)
[('hamburger', 'Emma\x00,Frank'), ('ice cream', 'Donald'), ('pizza', 'Adam\x00,Bob\x00,Charles')]
```

In fact if I change the separator in the `func.listagg()` to something else like `<->` instead of `,` then every character the forms the separator string is null-preceded:

```
>>> [print('{}: {}'.format(entry.food, entry.people)) for entry in entries]
hamburger: Emma<->Frank
ice cream: Donald
pizza: Adam<->Bob<->Charles 

>>> print(entries)
[('hamburger', 'Emma\x00<\x00-\x00>Frank'), ('ice cream', 'Donald'), ('pizza', 'Adam\x00<\x00-\x00>Bob\x00<\x00-\x00>Charles')]
```

Not sure what's going on there.  But if need be, it's easy enough to strip out the nulls from the column.  At least the hard part with the LISTAGG is done.

Comment: Could it be some misbehaving unicode conversion? Looks like UTF-16, double encoded or some such. Unfortunately I don't have access to an Oracle DB, so cannot test.

Comment: The columns themselves are VARCHAR, and of course the separator is just a python string.  It's very mysterious.  But at least there's an easy workaround.  Thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

`within_group` can take multiple arguments.  `func.listagg` takes what to group, followed by the separator, and within_group takes a list of what to order the group by.

```
query = ( select([func.listagg(A.list_value, ', ')
              .within_group(A.list_value, A.other_column)])
              .where(A.id == B.id)
              .label('list_values_of_a') )
```

This would translate to:

Group the list_value of A separated by a comma and a space,
 and ordered by A.list_value and then A.other_column
 when A.id is equal to B.id.

Hope that helps.