# creating and appending to a list in SQLAlchemy database table

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I am learning SQLAlchemy and I am stuck.
I have a SQL table (table1) has two fields: 'name' and 'other_names'

I have an excel file with two columns:

```
first_name alias   
paul   patrick
john   joe
simon  simone
john   joey
john   jo
```

I want to read the excel file into my table1, so that it looks like this (i.e. all of the aliases for the same line are on one row):

```
paul    patrick
john    joe,joey,jo
simon   simone
```

This is the idea that I was trying to do. The code (with comments) that I tried:

```
for line in open('file.txt', 'r'): #for each line in the excel file
        line = line.strip().split('\t') #split each line with a name and alias
        first_name = line[0] #first name is the name before the tab
        alias = line[1] #alias is the name after the tab
        instance = 
        Session.query(session,tbs['table1'].name).filter_by(name=first_name) #look through the database table, by name field, and see if the first name is there 
        list_instance = [x[0] for x in instance] #make a list of first names already in database table
        if first_name not in list_instance: #if the excel first name is not in the database table
              alias_list = [] #make an empty list
              alias_list.append(alias) #append the alias
              name_obj = lib.get_or_create( #small function to make db object
              session,
              tbs["table1"],
              name = first_name, #add first name to the name field
              other_names = alias_list # add alias list to the other_names field
            )


       elif first_name in list_instance: #elif first name already in db
             alias_list.append(alias) #append the alias to the alias list made above
             name_obj = lib.get_or_create(
             session,
             tbs["table1"],
             name = first_name,
             other_names = alias_list #create object as before, but use updated alias list
    )
```

The problem is that I can get the above code to run with no errors, but also the output is not an appended list, it is simply a database table that looks like the excel file; i.e.

```
name   alias
paul   patrick
john   joe
simon  simone
john   joey
john   jo
```

Could someone point out where I am going wrong, specifically, how do i amend this code? Please let me know if the question is unclear, I've tried to make it a simple example. Specifically, how do I initialise and add to lists as a field entry in a SQLalchemy db table.

Update 1: I have updated my code according to kind suggestion below. However I still have the issue. This is the full aim, code and test file:
The aim:

I have a table in the database (see below for test file going into table).The table has two fields, name (the latin name e.g. homo sapiens) and other names (the common names e.g. human, man). I want to update a field (other names) in the table, so instead of having:

```
Rana rugosa human   
Rana rugosa man 
Rana rugosa frog    
Rana rugosa cow
```

I have:

```
Rana rugosa human,man,frog,cow
```

The test_data file looks like this:

```
origin_organism        common_name         tested_organism
Rana rugosa            human                -
Rana rugosa            man                  -
Rana rugosa            frog                 homo sapiens
Rana rugosa            cow                  Rana rugosa
Rana rugosa            frog                 Rana rugosa
Rana rugosa            frog                 -
Rana rugosa            frog                 -
Rana rugosa            frog                homo sapiens
-                      -                   -
-                      -                   homo sapiens
-                      -                   -
-                      -                   -
-                      -                   -
-                      -                   -
streptococcus pneumoniae    -              -
```

The code:

```
import sys 
from sqlalchemy.orm  import * 
from sqlalchemy  import * 
from dbn.sqlalchemy_module  import lib 
import pd

engine = lib.get_engine(user="user", psw="pwd", db="db", db_host="111.111.111.11")
Base = lib.get_automapped_base(engine)
session = Session(engine)
tbs = lib.get_mapped_classes(Base)
session.rollback()
df = pd.read_excel('test_data.xlsx', sheet_name = 'test2')




for index, row in df.iterrows():  
    origin_latin_name = row['origin_organism'].strip().lower()
    other_names_name = row['common_name'].strip().lower()
    tested_species = row['tested_organism'].strip().lower()


if origin_latin_name not in [None, "None", "", "-"]:
    instance = [x[0] for x in Session.query(session,tbs['species'].name).filter_by(name=origin_latin_name).all()]
    if origin_latin_name not in instance:
        origin_species = lib.get_or_create(
            session,
            tbs["species"],
            name = origin_latin_name,
            other_names = other_names_name
        )

    elif origin_latin_name in instance:
        other_names_query = Session.query(session,tbs['species'].other_names).filter_by(name=origin_latin_name)
        other_names_query_list = [x for x in other_names_query]
        original_list2 = list(set([y for y in x[0].split(',') for x in other_names_query_list]))
        if other_names_name not in original_list2:
            original_list2.append(other_names_name)
            new_list = ','.join(original_list2)
            new_names = {'other_names':','.join(original_list2)}

        origin_species = lib.get_or_create(
            session,
            tbs["species"],
            name = origin_latin_name,
            other_names = new_list
        )
```

The part from the elif statement doesn't work. I've ran into two problems:

(1) The most recent error I got:
NameError: name 'new_list' is not defined

(2) another error I got is that I have another table further on

```
map1 = lib.get_or_create(
    session,
    tbs["map1"],
    age_id_id = age,
    name_id_id = origin_species.id
    )
```

...and it said that origin_species cannot be found, but I think this is linked to the elif statement, that somehow the origin_species object is not being updated properly.

If anyone could help I would appreciate it.

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on how to debug your code.

Comment: I think this will work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48799232/is-there-a-listagg-within-group-equivalent-in-sqlalchemy?rq=1. You may possibly need `pd.to_sql()` to push DataFrame to your DB

Comment: everything under `elif` will not get assigned if the conditions don't execute it. So `elif origin_latin_name in instance`

Comment: Everything you want to do doesn't need to be done with SQL alchemy. You are importing pandas. Just import your table into pandas and use a groupby statement. I'd be willing to show you if you are okay with only using MySQL alchemy to hold the data

Comment: Is there an acceptable answer here?

Answer (score 3):

Simple mistake. You aren't giving it a list. I'm not sure why they end up in different rows, however, I would change the following because at the moment I don't see where you split the names into a list, all I see is you assigning a string onto a list using append.

```
alias_list = alias.split(',')
```

Which could also be:

```
alias_list = line[1].split(',')
```

Output:

```
alias_list:    ['Name1','Name2','Name3']
```

Currently your code outputs:

```
alias_list = ['Name1,Name2,Name3']
```

Which, whilst it is technically a list by data type, it is a worthless list for the way you want to use it. This is because `alias_list[0]` would return the entire string, as opposed to `'Name1'`

WORD OF WARNING:

Your code is creating a list unnecessarily. You don't need a list in your database, you can easily achieve what you wabt by using the string that is evaluated when you read the excel file.

What you should do IMHO is to store the string of names as a whole string, then if you need to query the aliases of someone, then you can split the string on the other side, if that makes sense?

Comment: Thank you. I have updated my code according to your suggestions (originally I had changed the variable names just for simplicity, but I have now kept all the data exactly as original just to show exactly what I've done). If you have any thoughts I would appreciate it.

Comment: Also, in case it helps, I found a potentially great StackOverflow answer here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667138/how-to-update-sqlalchemy-row-entry, and I've tried to apply the information to this question, but I'm clearly doing something wrong.

Comment: To @Swift 's  Word Of Warning: another approach could be to directly query this and get your results prepared by the DB instead - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44949384/1896134   Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you use a groupby statement with the pandas dataframe you can easily do this. Code is untested let me know if there are errors

```
import sys 
from sqlalchemy.orm  import * 
from sqlalchemy  import * 
from dbn.sqlalchemy_module  import lib 
import pd

engine = lib.get_engine(user="user", psw="pwd", db="db", db_host="111.111.111.11")

###Get test data
added_df = pd.read_excel('test_data.xlsx', sheet_name = 'test2')

###Get current database as a pandas object
my_current_df = pd.read_sql_table(
        "table1", engine)

#Now group by origin organism
gb = added_df.groupby('origin_organism')

#For every member that had the same origin organism, return it as a comma seperated list into a new dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(gb.alias.apply(lambda x: ",".join(x)))

#Now append that dataframe onto the one that came from the database
my_current_df.append(df)

#NOw return that dataframe back to the database
my_current_df.to_sql(
        name='table1',
        con=engine,
        if_exists='replace')
```